# How to Read a Record in php that has composite (multi-column) primary key

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a database application. and I m having trouble with Processing  a table in php It uses two columns as its primary key. I have built the index page and the insert page and they are working fine but the delete,edit and detail page are giving trouble.
Here is the html for detail page

```
            <div class="span10 offset1">
                <div class="row">
                    <h3>Section Details</h3>
                </div>

                <div class="form-horizontal" >
                  <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Act No :</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <?php echo $data['ActNo'];?>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                         <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Section No :</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <?php echo $data['SectionNo'];?>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                  </div> 
                    <div class="form-actions">
                      <a class="btn" href="index.php">Back</a>
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>

</div> <!-- /container -->
```

and here is the php Code

```
   <?php

require '../../AppData/database.php';
$id = null; 
if ( !empty($_GET['ActNo'])) {
    $id = $_REQUEST['ActNo'];
}
$sec = null;
if ( !empty($_GET['SectionNo'])) {
    $id = $_REQUEST['SectionNo'];
}

if ( null==$id && null==$sec ) {
    header("Location: index.php");
} else {
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM section where ActNo = ? AND SectionNo= ?";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($id, $sec));
    $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    Database::disconnect();
}
   ?>
```

When I click The detail link on index page. the data is sent through url. I can see that both values are sent properly in url but they are not recived on the next page.

I dont have much experience with POST and GET and REQUEST and i think that is where the problem is occuring. please take a look and tell me what is wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: Warning: `if(null==$id || null==$sec)`. Because I think if one of them is missing, you should redirect. Also can you echo $id and $sec variables in last else block?

Comment: I dont see why i should echo it in last else block. This code has previously worked for me with single column key. but now its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found the problem. Here is the modified code.

```
 <?php

require '../../AppData/database.php';
$id=null ; 
if ( !empty($_GET['ActNo'])) {
    $id = $_REQUEST['ActNo'];
}
$sec=null ;
if (  !empty($_GET['SectionNo'])) {
    $sec = $_REQUEST['SectionNo'];
}

if ( null==$id || null==$sec ) {
    header("Location: index.php");
} else {
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM section where ActNo = ? AND SectionNo= ?";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($id, $sec));
    $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    Database::disconnect();
}
  ?>
```

### Now this is working fine. I suppose there was a problem at line #10 I entered $id instead od $sec.

Now could someone help me with the delete module? here is the code..

require '../../AppData/database.php';
    $id = 0;

```
if ( !empty($_GET['ActNo'])) {
    $id = $_REQUEST['ActNo'];
}
$sec = 0;
if ( !empty($_GET['SectionNo'])) {
    $sec = $_REQUEST['SectionNo'];
}

if ( !empty($_POST)) {
    // keep track post values
    $id = $_POST['ActNo'];
    $sec = $_POST['SectionNo'];

    // delete data
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "DELETE FROM section  WHERE ActNo = ? AND SectionNo = ?";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($id, $sec));
    Database::disconnect();
    header("Location: index.php");

}
   ?>
```

Comment: Create a new question for your new problem.